# Comparison between pointer and integer(id and int) in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

While running this

```
if([SUPApplication ConnectionStatus]==[SUPConnectionStatus_DISCONNECTED])
{......

 ......}
```

we are getting a warning like "comparison between pointer and integer(id and int)" Why like that.Is there any functions to parse both into same datatype.

Comment: What data type is `[SUPApplication ConnectionStatus]`?

Comment: @yulz its data type is "int32_t"

Comment: @yulz connectionStatus is of datatype int32_t which is already declared in SUPApplication

Comment: How the hell is this working: `[SUPConnectionStatus_DISCONNECTED]`?

Comment: Did you `#import` the header that declares `SUPApplication` and its `ConnectionStatus` method? Are you sure you spelled the class and method names correctly?

Comment: @yulz Please don't mek corrections to code by editing the post: point out and explain the change in your answer.

Comment: How SUPConnectionStatus_DISCONNECTED is defined ? Remove square bracket around SUPConnectionStatus_DISCONNECTED, you are not sending message to an object, nor using a C array.

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast them:

```
if((int)[SUPApplication ConnectionStatus]== (int)SUPConnectionStatus_DISCONNECTED)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making them both into `NSNumbers` and then compare there values

```
if ([[NSNumber numberWithInt:[SUPApplication ConnectionStatus]] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:SUPConnectionStatus_DISCONNECTED]])
{
  .... 
}
```